# \textit -command gives "Package inputenc Error"

Tags: compiling, texshop

I'm using the `classicthesis` template with TeXShop version 3.52 (3.52) on OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 (14E46).

I've been using the command `\textit` for italics in my project successfully for more than a year, but have been recently getting a bizarre compiling error.

Please look at the console output as TeXShop console doesn't allow copying for failed compiles:

[image: console output]

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Not sure that the error actually is at that point. Could you try making a fully minimal example and post that do others can test it?

Comment: Just in case: Did you check TeXshop saves your files in UTF8 encoding, not in applemac?

Comment: Open the log-file called classicThesis.log and copy the relevant part to the questionn as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The string `\textit{test}` consists of ASCII characters, which are not touched by package `inputenc`. The string only happens to appear on the line of the error. The problematic character is elsewhere on the line.

Often this error is caused by an unbreakable space character U+00A0.
Delete the rest of the line or rewrite the whole line and try again.

Also a hex viewer can be used to analyze the characters on the line.